# Entrega contínua

Tags: php, apache

Visto que quando desenvolvemos um sistema em PHP local sem qualquer tipo de framework apenas utilizando os paradigmas de Orientação a objetos, qual a melhor forma de entregar este sistema continuamente ou seja entrega em fases?

O fato que acontece bastante é em um desenvolvimento local geralmente se faz alguns `Head("Destino")` e quando passamos isso para produção ai muda de figura pois é tanto `Head('localhost')` contido que fica bem oneroso entregar satisfatoriamente o sistema que agora possui um IP diferente no lugar, alguma sugestão?

Comment: Se o problema é só alterar URLs porque não usar constantes globais ou envelopadas em uma classe? por exemplo: MeuServidor.'/Resto da URL/', dessa forma você só precisaria alterar o valor dessa constante na inicialização do site indicando se é produção ou não.

Comment: Fazes ou Fases?

Comment: Este problema não parece com PHP ou apache, parece um problema de desenvolvimento do trabalho, um problema de cliente e desenvolvedor (programador). Poderia deixar a sua pergunta um pouco mais clara, pra eu ter certeza se 'e isto mesmo?